# Flutter: image border increases in a wide screen

Tags: flutter

narrow screen

[image]

wide screen

[image]

Whenever I widen the web page, the margin around the photo increase. Is there someway to prevent this from happening?

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Firebase Meetup'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            width: 50,
            child: Image.asset('assets/codelab.png'),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 8),
          const IconAndDetail(Icons.calendar_today, 'October 30'),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

MediaQuery.of(context)

To get Screen width:

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
```

To get Screen height: `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`

Comment: Then? Can you be more specific?